# How can I use if in SQL query

Tags: laravel, octobercms

Can SQL also run a query like the following? So first we will look at a value, accordingly we will look at other values.

```
SELECT * FROM IF WHERE `status` != 'true' ELSE WHERE `status_2` == 'false'
```

So how can we adapt this in laravel october CMS as below.

```
$query->whereHas('avaibleDates', function($q) {
    if ( $q->where('start_date', '<=', 2) ) {
        $q->where('status_id', '!=', 2);
    }
});
```

So we want to run a query according to one situation and another query according to another situation.

Comment: Take a look at orWhere() : https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#or-where-clauses

Comment: yes it works that way, thanks. So how can we use this for the whereHas query? @GertB.

Comment: There is a orWhereHas() function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description, I do not quite understand what you want to do)). I think you need casts something like this:

```
   $query->whereHas('avaibleDates', function($q) {
        $q->where(function ($q) {
            $q->where('start_date', '<=', 2)->where('status_id', '!=', 2);
        });
        // The following conditions
            
        ...
    
        $q->orWhere(function ($q) {
            $q->where('start_date', '>', 55)->where('status_id', '!=', 7);
        });
    
        ...
    
    });
```